# Why does a similar cursed spirit manifest at Yasohachi Bridge as had manifested at the juvenile detention center?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

In episodes 23 and 24 of Jujutsu Kaisen, we find out that one of the fingers of Ryomen Sukuna has been hiding its presence at Yasohachi Bridge since many years, and has only become active since Itadori Yuuji first consumed a finger a few months prior. In these two episodes, Fushiguro Megumi is forced to confront a special grade cursed spirit that manifested from the cursed energy of Sukuna's finger at Yasohachi Bridge.

[image: The special grade cursed spirit at Yasohachi Bridge.]

What confuses me is that this special grade cursed spirit has the same appearance and personality as the one that metamorphosed from the curse womb at the juvenile detention center, which Yuuji, Megumi and Kugisaki Nobara investigated in episodes 4 and 5. A finger of Sukuna was responsible for manifesting that special grade cursed spirit, too.

[image: The special grade cursed spirit at the juvenile detention center.]

**Question:** Is it the case that any cursed spirit that a finger of Sukuna brings into manifestation will have the same form? If not, how did the cursed spirits at the juvenile detention center and Yasohachi Bridge appear so similar (one might even say identical)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it the case that any cursed spirit that a finger of Sukuna brings into manifestation will have the same form?

Yes, they are called [Finger Bearers](https://jujutsu-kaisen.fandom.com/wiki/Finger_Bearer). They are cursed spirit that becomes a special grade after they devour one of Sukuna's fingers. Finger Bearers begin as cursed wombs where they gestate until birth. During this period they can be seen by non-sorcerers. Once born they create an Innate Domain, a precursor to a Domain Expansion, that warps the dimensions of its birthplace.

Finger bearers appeared in both Cursed Womb Arc(ep 4-5) and Death Painting Arc(ep 23-24).